# How to choose architecture of neural network for concrete task?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

I am new in deep learning, and I am a bit confused about one question: how do you systematically choose the architecture of your neural network (NN) for a concrete task?

For example, I am solving a classification task with 3 classes (the NN should recognize pandas, dogs and cats). What I am doing now is just taking architecture, which has 90% accuracy on CIFAR-10 dataset, and trying to apply it to my task. Results are not so good (on 30 epoch I got only about 40% accuracy on train set and 57% on val set).

What type of architecture I should choose? Is there a general rule of thumb?

Comment: When you trained your model using the CIFAR-10 architecture, how did you choose the learning rate? How did you configure the optimizer? How did you decide when to stop training? What happens if you use a different learning rate, or train the model for longer, or use a different optimizer configuration?